# AS3 - Error 1119: Access of possibly undefined property enemyList through a reference with static type Class.

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to get access to a variable from another class and I keep getting error '1119: Access of possibly undefined property enemyList through a reference with static type Class.' I can't see what I do wrong since my variable is made 'public' and 'static'.

class where the variable is made.

```
package classes.enemy
{   
imports ...

public class Enemy extends MovieClip
{
    public static var enemyList:Array = new Array(); **
    var speed:Number;

    public function initialize()
    {
        var stageReff:Stage = this.stage as Stage;
        addEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);
    }

    public function Enemy() 
    {
        enemyList.push(this); **
        this.x = 700;
        this.y = Math.random()*200 + 50;
        speed = Math.random()*5 + 5;
    }

    //code
}
}
```

class that needs access to the variable

```
package classes.ship 
{
imports ...

public class Bullet extends MovieClip
{
    var speed:Number;

    public function initialize()
    {
        var stageReff:Stage = this.stage as Stage;
        stage.addEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);
    }

    //code

    function enterFrame(e:Event):void
    {
        this.x += speed;

        trace(enemy.enemyList); **
    }
}   
}
```

Putted '**' behind the lines where the problem occurs and where the variable is made, just to make it clear.

Classes are in different folders (classes > enemy & classes > ship), don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access a static property, you need to use the class it is defined in: `Enemy.enemyList`

Also make sure the class is imported properly in your ship's class: `import classes.enemy.Enemy;`

Comment: I assume the lower case `enemy` is just a typo. If not, I will gladly expand my answer with more information.

Comment: If I do that I get: 1120: Access of undefined property Enemy.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem and the solution is:

your class name is "enemy" and when you access it, it remains as class not object

try to make an object of your class

```
enemy1 = new enemy(); // in your bullet class
```

or if bullet is a movieclip in which enemy as its child movieclip, then change its instance name to enemy1 so you can access it as an object of its own class defination "enemy"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with error 1119 on as3.

I was pulling my hair off and then I noticed that there was an output message related to TLF text.

So I went to action script settings on the FLA file and merged into code the textlayout library.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Update 1 :

Don't forget also to **import your class `Enemy`**

I suppose that `enemy` in `Bullet` is a class instance, so *you can't call a static property from an instance* you need to call it with the class name where it is declared:

so in Bullet `enemy` should be `Enemy`

```
package classes.ship {
    //...
    import enemy.Enemy;
    //...

    function enterFrame(e:Event):void
    {
     this.x += speed;
     trace(Enemy.enemyList); **
    }
```

Comment: If I do that I get: 1120: Access of undefined property Enemy.

Comment: @Robbe Van Winckel updated the answer don't forget to import your class Enemy from the enemy package.